# How to find the area of the slice of a circle?

Tags: area

Let us have a circle of radius $1$, which is placed on $X$-$Y$ plane. The center of the circle is at $(0.5,0.5)$.

If I cut a slice of the circle at $x=0.3$, how to find the area of the slice?

Is there a formula which is a function of $x$ and radius?

Comment: Your question is about the area but the tag is volume?

Comment: Find the angle $\theta$ subtended by the slice at the center. Then the area of the slice is $\dfrac{1}{2}(\theta - \sin\theta)$.

Comment: @Chris Varghese, what if the radius is r?

Comment: @Dimitrios just multiply by $r^2$, but note that $\theta$ itself depends on $r$.

Answer (score 0):

All points $(x,y)$ on the circle satisfy
$$
(x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 = 1^2
$$
Assuming the slice is the part with less area, we have e.g.
$$
A = \int\limits_{-1/2}^{0.3} \,\,\,\int\limits_{y_-(x)}^{y_+(x)} dy \, dx
$$
where
$$
y_\pm(x) = (1/2) \pm \sqrt{1 - (x - 1/2)^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a circle of radius $R$ and your cutting from a slice by a straight line segment that is $a$ units away from the center.  The area of the slice of the area of the circular sector (like a pizza slice) minus the area of the triangle formed by the end points of the cutting line segment with the center of the circle.

Since the cutting line is $a$ units from the center then the chord length is

$ c = 2 \sqrt{ R^2 - a^2 } $

And half the angle of the circular sector mentioned above is

$ \theta = \cos^{-1} \dfrac{ a }{R } $

Therefore, the area of the cut out slice is

$ \text{Slice Area} = \dfrac{1}{2} R^2 (2 \theta ) - \dfrac{1}{2} R^2 \sin(2 \theta ) $

This simplifies to

$ \text{Slice Area} =  R^2 \cos^{-1} \left(\dfrac{a}{R}\right) - a \sqrt{ R^2 - a^2 } $